# To get value of file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code i have a dynamic file upload i want to get value .Pls help me to get value .

```
var counter = 0;
     function AddFileUpload() {
                var div = document.createElement('DIV');
                div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" value="doc"  name = "file' + counter +
        '" type="file" />';
    }
```

Code:

```
 $("[id^=file]").on("change", function (e) {

});
```

Comment: Read about getting values of input field in javascript

Comment: google up FileReader JS

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery code if you have *file* as ID of the file input control:

```
$("#file").on("change", function (e) {
 var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
});
```

you can get name and size of the file as

```
$("#file").on("change", function (e) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var fileName = file.name;
    var filesize = file.size;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of an input file field just like other types of input fields. In your case, add this.

```
   var file1 = $("#file").val();
```

To get extension of the file

```
   var ext1 = file1.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
```

To get size of the file

```
   var size = $("#file")[0].files[0].size;
```